# Google Maps Javascript API v3: google.maps is not whitelisted for your application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to my application but am receiving the error that my app is not whitelisted. I have tried loading the API in two ways:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'table']});
google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: function(){
}});
</script>
```

Loading it this way causes the error that my app is not whitelisted. I have tried to include the key within the other_parameters but receive the same error. The API is enabled in the Developer Console. The appropriate referrers are enabled in the Console as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...">
    </script>
```

Loading it this way causes the error that the object google is not extensible.

Thank you in advance for help.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/loader/#AvailableAPIs) for the Google Loader is not current and does not show how a key should be included in the loader

Thank you

Comment: According to documentation Google Loader does not support Maps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried to do it that way because the other way was causing an error that object google is not extensible.